# Xpath for element with colon in element name

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

my xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EntityDescriptor ID="_2d6175bd-f939-49f2-a980-db4179f32074" entityID="https://server1.domain.com:xx3/yyy/" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
  <RoleDescriptor xsi:type="fed:ApplicationServiceType" xmlns:fed="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706" protocolSupportEnumeration="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <fed:ClaimTypesRequested>
      <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity" Optional="true" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" />
    </fed:ClaimTypesRequested>
    <fed:TargetScopes>
      <EndpointReference xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <Address>https://baarnntl1/</Address>
      </EndpointReference>
    </fed:TargetScopes>
    <fed:PassiveRequestorEndpoint>
      <EndpointReference xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <Address>https://baarnntl1/</Address>
      </EndpointReference>
    </fed:PassiveRequestorEndpoint>
  </RoleDescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

I want to change the address element value

```
XmlDocument fedMetaDocument = new XmlDocument();
fedMetaDocument.Load(federatedMetadataFile);
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(fedMetaDocument.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("fed", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706");

foreach (XmlNode targetScopeNode in fedMetaDocument.SelectNodes("TargetScopes/EndpointReference/Address", mgr))
{
    targetScopeNode.Value = tsakListUrl;
}
foreach (XmlNode PassiveRequestorEndpointNode in fedMetaDocument.SelectNodes("TargetScopes/EndpointReference/Address", mgr))
{
    PassiveRequestorEndpointNode.Value = tsakListUrl;
}
```

I am getting an error

```
  System.Xml.XPath.XPathException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
  Source=System.Xml
  StackTrace:
       at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseNodeTest(AstNode qyInput, AxisType axisType, XPathNodeType nodeType)
       at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseStep(AstNode qyInput)
       at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseRelativeLocationPath(AstNode qyInput)
```

Comment: Your xml doesn't look like xml to me!

Comment: I dont see XML in the problem statement

Comment: @vickirk: Should flag for mod attention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps...try code below:

```
foreach (XmlNode targetScopeNode in fedMetaDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Address"))
{
  targetScopeNode.InnerText = tsakListUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your XPath expression should contain the namespace when selecting a node with a namespace applied. [Reference]

So the XPath expressions should be the following

```
//fed:TargetScope/EndpointReference/Address
```

instead of

```
//TargetScope/EndpointReference/Address
```

Comment: You'll also need to map the prefix `fed:` to the appropriate namespace per the `xmlns:fed`.

Comment: He did that in `mgr.AddNamespace`

Comment: Not only does the OP need the namespace prefix for the fed namespace, but will also need to declare and use a prefix for the default namespace, "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to

```
mgr.AddNamespace("fed", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706");
```

you need to declare a prefix for the default namespace:

```
mgr.AddNamespace("meta", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata");
```

And then use it on all elements that are in that namespace:

```
fedMetaDocument.SelectNodes("fed:TargetScopes/meta:EndpointReference/meta:Address", mgr))
```

Namespaces are one of those things that, if you don't understand the fundamentals, will really trip you up if you try to just get them to work by trial and error. See [this earlier answer of mine about the default namespace and XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111202/select-default-namespace-in-xpath-with-htmlunit/6112334#6112334).