# Can not transform correctly using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I tried to use a XSLT transformation (below) to a RSS with this type with no result. Why is that ?

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" media="screen" href="/~d/styles/atom10full.xsl"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~d/styles/itemcontent.css"?>

<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:feedburner="http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0" gd:etag="W/&quot;CUACQXg6fyp7ImA9WhdUFUo.&quot;">
```

and the structure of it is

```
<feed>
tags tags tags like <title></title>
<entry><published></published><title></title><content></content>....</entry>
</feed>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:include href="identity.xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is an FAQ. Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111202/select-default-namespace-in-xpath-with-htmlunit. Also, "no result" is confusing... it sounds like it means "no output", but there should be a result document that is equivalent to the input document, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stylesheet is constructed for the default XML namespace (xmlns=""). An RSS feed has the Atom (xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom") namespace defined and possibly others if you have nested XML content.

To 'match' anything in that namespace, you need to define it in your stylesheet also. You probably want to define Atom with a prefix like: xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom". Then your match would become

```
<xsl:template match="a:entry"/>
```

Also, the above matches entry but you're not doing anything with it. You probably want it to print out a transformed value when you get an entry but the above is just excluding it from the result.

Comment: I now get it.. Also I see some tags like `<app:edited>`. How do I match them ? I tried `a:app:edited` but I got errors

Comment: @Giorkouros Namespaces are flat. You can match with simply "app:edited".